# DWM Unicode Support

Tags: linux, c, unicode, dwm

I'm in the process of creating a nice looking statusbar with DWM and I want to implement unicode symbols with font awesome. Supposedly I can use the Pango patch but its out of date (for version 6.1) so patching fails. Is there another method I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an [XFT patch for 6.1](https://lists.suckless.org/dev/1407/23054.html) posted to the mailing list some time ago: that should work.

Your only other option is to update pango for 6.1, which may be a significant task given the changes to dwm over that version bump.